# Rails 4: use different server port depending on environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, environment-variables, boot

I'm trying to automate the configuration of my rails application and I want to be able to start the app without specifying the port, as I would like it to be chosen depending on the environment.

Specifically (something simple to start with) to run the application on port 3000 if environment is production, on port 3500 otherwise.

So, following this answer, I've added the following to my boot.rb file:

```
require 'rails/commands/server'

module DefaultOptions
  def default_options
    super.merge!(Port: Rails.env.production? ? 3000 : 3500)
  end
end

Rails::Server.send(:prepend, DefaultOptions)
```

Unfortunately I'm doing something wrong, because this is the output when I run `rails s`:

```
/home/luca/projects/ads_manager/config/boot.rb:10:in `default_options': undefined method `env' for Rails:Module (NoMethodError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:287:in `parse_options'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:184:in `options'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:58:in `set_environment'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:42:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `new'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Any idea why Rails.env is not available?

Alternatives to obtain the same result are more than welcome indeed.

Comment: @Gopalrathore I don't see how it could change the port. Can you explain a little bit more? Does it mean "do this only if it's not production"?

Comment: simply it sets a port for production environment, for development the default will used that is 3000.

Comment: does it works for u correctly? ... actually I didn't tested it.

Comment: You removed the code, I couldn't try it. Anyway, I want to do the opposite: port 3000 for production, 3500 for the other envs.

Comment: Maybe instead of `Rails.env.production?` something like: `(ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || 'development') == 'production'`

Comment: @Aguardientico doesn't give me the error anymore, but `ENV['RAILS_ENV']` apparently is empty.

Comment: How are you starting server at prod? if RAILS_ENV is empty then try with RACK_ENV

Comment: @Aguardientico I start the server with `rails s -e production`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using *NIX systems, you can try the following

In your terminal run the command below

`export RAILS_ENV=production`

***NOTE:*** This will set the environment to production temporarily, if you need this permanently, add this to your .bashrc file

And then start your application server.

Inside the boot.rb file, use `ENV['RAILS_ENV']` instead of `Rails.env`

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've tried it on my local machine and it worked :) BTW I wonder what happens when you want to run different environments (say production and development) on the same machine. I guess this approach implies to have to different users with their `.bashrc` file set up properly. Am I right?

Comment: Adding the environment to `.bashrc` is not a compulsion. You can also use it in the command for starting your rails server using the following method `RAILS_ENV=development rails s`

Comment: yeah, edit your answer to include mine, way to go, bro!

Comment: Hey @DeeY, here is a screenshot which shows the first version of my answer. Kindly have a look at the time-stamp mentioned there, and then compare it to the time on which you submitted the answer. Its pretty clear who copied the answer http://bmp.io/noPSTlV

Comment: And here is another screenshot, which shows, what parts of my answer I had edited. http://bmp.io/cuXwGWN

Comment: Don't worry @Rohit, so far you're answer is way more complete than his.

Answer (score 2):

I would tried your solution just changing the `Rails.env.production?`to `ENV["RAILS_ENV"] != "production"` and it works :) So:

```
require 'rails/commands/server'

module DefaultOptions
  def default_options
    super.merge!(Port: ENV["RAILS_ENV"] == "production" ? 3000 : 3500)
  end
end

Rails::Server.send(:prepend, DefaultOptions)
```

Answer (score 1):

Rails.env is set later during the rails boot process, can you try checking ENV["RAILS_ENV"] instead?